# Lua - Infinite loop

Tags: sdk, lua

Would something like this ever work?

```
local a = 2
for i=0, a do
   i = i + 1
   a = a + 1
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was just asking if, by doing this, every time it loops, it adds one more time he needs to loop, making it an infinite loop.

Comment: -1: For lack of research. [Lua's documentation clearly shows how a for loop is evaluated.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.4.5)

Answer (score 4):

Define "work".

That will loop from 0 to 2, because Lua only *reads the value once*. It only evaluates the expressions one time, the initial time. After that, it stores them in local variables that you cannot find or alter and does its testing from there.